# How to pass pk in reverse() for generics.DestroyAPIView?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm writing test for my endpoint responsible for deleting objects. I'm struggling with passing proper pk of object. It is keeping me prompting with `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch`.

My url:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(
    prefix="questions-api/delete", viewset=views.QuestionDelete, basename="questions_delete"
)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

The way I'm calling `reverse`:

```
    response = api_client.delete(
        reverse("questions_delete-list", kwargs={'pk':1}),
    )
```

Appreciate any hint :)

Comment: As far as I know ```list``` is being added to basename from deafult if it comes to reverse.

Answer (score 0):

```
 reverse('questions_delete-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.instance.pk})
```

**{self.instance.pk}** get id of the model instance